# Reading a JSON response from FireFox console

Tags: ruby, json, firefox, selenium, automated-tests

I have tried searching a bit for an answer but am having trouble, as I think this scenario is a little 'unique' in that the JSON file is coming from a server response after calling a method.

When you input example.Server.method() into the FireFox console manually, you get a JSON response. I want to input this into the console in a ruby script with selenium webdriver, so I can read an important piece of information from the JSON response.

I'm thinking I can call the method like so:

```
console.log("example.Server.method()")
```

But where does the JSON response actually 'go', since I want my script to find and parse the information? Calling the method results in a examplename.json file that I need to parse.

Answer (score 2):

You could execute the java script like so

```
information = driver.execute_script("return example.Server.method()")
```

Comment: Thank you, this has definitely gotten me closer. But where does the json file 'go' - the variable just returns 'nil' when I output the value to the terminal.